# Displaying a single sentence of the div

Tags: php, javascript, css

I want to show the first line of a div with "..." appened at the end, and then reveal the whole block removing "..." on click. Also, I'd like to know how to toggle it back to the compact one-line version on a second click.

Is there an easy way to do this through javascript? I use jQuery.

Comment: The triple dot is called an elipsis. With that information you can easily run a search to find a jQuery elipsis plugin, there are many to choose from.

Comment: This functionality is really simple to implement yourself... I don't believe that it warrants a plugin...

Comment: @Lix, not quite so. if you want a method that looks good in presentation you will have to use something other than substr(). it will cut words off whenever it reaches the limit. you would have to know the sentence you're truncating ahead of time and count the characters so it doesn't end up cutting off any words.

Comment: Using *only* `substr()` would leave some holes in the logic - I agree with you... but there are simple things that are possible to prevent those instances - splitting sentences by spaces (by words) would prevent cutting a word in half - if there are too many characters then you take off another word and recalculate.

Comment: My only point was that it is not always necessary to bloat a web app full of simplistic plugins that could just as easily have been developed in house to be more customized and robust.

Comment: @Lix, not sure how splitting a sentence with a space is going to prevent word cutting, maybe update your example? my point was that there are plugins out there to help and they are definitely not bloated and you should not frown upon their use. they are developed by smart people and can be as customized and robust as anything you'd make in-house. and if they aren't... expand on them and let the author know! take a look at [ThreeDots](http://theproductguy.com/threedots/threedots.demo.html). really helped when I had to insert dynamic text into a constrained area of varying heights and widths.

Answer (score 1):

The method I usually use is to place the two versions of the text (short and long) next to each other in the HTML.  One is hidden (the longer one) and when you click on it, your jQuery can just swap between the two elements...

You can use PHP's [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function to prepare your strings...

```
echo substr("This is a long line of text",0,9) . '...';

// This is a...
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick response Lix.
But the problem with  truncating the sentence by number of characters is , sometimes the text is showing up in two sentences.
Is there anyother solution?

Comment: @sav Can you explain what you mean by 2 sentences?  If thee are two sentences, there will still be a short version, and when you change the texts, the longer 2 sentences will be displayed...  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "Two birds flew over the rainbow. The second bird had a stroke.";
$shorten = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, '.')) . '...';
```

That shortens the text to the first sentence, assuming you don't have any abbreviated titles.

The jQuery is simple as well.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toggle').hide();
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $('#toggle').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<?php echo $shorten; ?>
<br /><a href="#" class="toggle">read more</a>
<div id="toggle"><?php echo $string; ?></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Marcus. But the problem with truncating the sentence by number of characters is , sometimes the text is showing up in two lines. Is there anyother solution?

Comment: I'm only truncating up to the first instance of a period. If there are multiple lines within the first sentence, I can only assume that the text has breaks in it. In that case you could say `$shorten = substr(strip_tags($string), 0, strpos(strip_tags($string), '.')) . '...';`

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution but should work...

```
div span { display:none; }
div b { font-weight:normal; }

<div>Blah blah blah blah<b>...</b> <span>blah blah blah blah blah</span></div>


jQuery("div").toggle(function() {
        $(this).find("b").hide();
        $(this).find("span").show();
  },
  function() {
        $(this).find("b").show();
        $(this).find("span").hide();
  }).
```

Comment: but my main aim is not displaying the first sentence of the div. my aim is to display the first line in the div.